# euclidean distance between RDD elements and broadcast variable

Tags: pyspark

```
from math import*
import numpy as np
def distanceBetweenTuples(data1 , data2) :
squaredSum = 0.0
for i in range(data1.count()):
squaredSum =  (np.array(data1)-np.array(data2))**2
return(squaredSum**0.5)
x=[(1,0,1),(1,2,1),(0,0,0)]
x=sc.parallelize(x)
y=[(1,0,1),(1,0,1)]
b=sc.broadcast(y)
c=x.mapPartitions(distanceBetweenTuples(x,b.value))
```

i want to calculate the euclidean distance between broadcast variable a RDd but giving error like below

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'RDD' and 'int'
```